# Finding most common key in Reducer, Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I need to find the most common key emitted by Mapper in the Reducer. My reducer works fine in this way:

```
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();
    private TreeMap<Double, Text> k_closest_points= new TreeMap<Double, Text>();
    public void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        int K = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("K"));
        for (Text value : values) {
            String v[] = value.toString().split("@");    //format of value from mapper: "Key@1.2345"
            double distance = Double.parseDouble(v[1]);
            k_closest_points.put(distance, new Text(value));    //finds the K smallest distances
            if (k_closest_points.size() > K)
                k_closest_points.remove(k_closest_points.lastKey());
        }
        for (Text t : k_closest_points.values())    //it perfectly emits the K smallest distances and keys
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), t);
    }
}
```

It finds the K instances with the smallest distances and writes to the output file. But I need to find the most common key in my TreeMap. So I'm trying it like below:

```
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();
    private TreeMap<Double, Text> k_closest_points = new TreeMap<Double, Text>();

    public void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        int K = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("K"));
        for (Text value : values) {
            String v[] = value.toString().split("@");
            double distance = Double.parseDouble(v[1]);
            k_closest_points.put(distance, new Text(value));
            if (k_closest_points.size() > K)
                k_closest_points.remove(k_closest_points.lastKey());
        }
        TreeMap<String, Integer> class_counts = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Text value : k_closest_points.values()) {
            String[] tmp = value.toString().split("@");
            if (class_counts.containsKey(tmp[0]))
                class_counts.put(tmp[0], class_counts.get(tmp[0] + 1));
            else
                class_counts.put(tmp[0], 1);
        }
        context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(class_counts.lastKey()));
    }
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at KNN$MyReducer.reduce(KNN.java:108)
        at KNN$MyReducer.reduce(KNN.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
```

Can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: `double distance = Double.parseDouble(v[1]);` This is where it's happening. Are you sure there's an "@" in the value?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure. The first version's output is like this: Corsa@0.1951866287909985. And also the first one works without any problems.

Comment: Check the size of `v` and `tmp` to narrow the possibilites down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things... first, your problem is here:

```
double distance = Double.parseDouble(v[1]);
```

You're splitting on `"@"` and it may not be in the string. If it's not, it will throw the `OutOfBoundsException`. I would add a clause like:

```
if(v.length < 2)
    continue;
```

Second (and this shouldn't even compile unless I'm crazy), `tmp` is a `String[]`, and yet here you're actually just concatenating `'1'` to it in the `put` operation (it's a parenthesis issue):

```
class_counts.put(tmp[0], class_counts.get(tmp[0] + 1));
```

It should be:

```
class_counts.put(tmp[0], class_counts.get(tmp[0]) + 1);
```

It's also expensive to look the key up twice in a potentially large `Map`. Here's how I'd re-write your reducer based on what you've given us (this is totally untested):

```
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();
    private TreeMap<Double, Text> k_closest_points = new TreeMap<Double, Text>();

    public void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        int K = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("K"));

        for (Text value : values) {
            String v[] = value.toString().split("@");
            if(v.length < 2)
                continue; // consider adding an enum counter

            double distance = Double.parseDouble(v[1]);
            k_closest_points.put(distance, new Text(v[0])); // you've already split once, why do it again later?

            if (k_closest_points.size() > K)
                k_closest_points.remove(k_closest_points.lastKey());
        }


        // exit early if nothing found
        if(k_closest_points.isEmpty())
            return;


        TreeMap<String, Integer> class_counts = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Text value : k_closest_points.values()) {
            String tmp = value.toString();
            Integer current_count = class_counts.get(tmp);

            if (null != current_count) // avoid second lookup
                class_counts.put(tmp, current_count + 1);
            else
                class_counts.put(tmp, 1);
        }

        context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(class_counts.lastKey()));
    }
}
```

Next, and more semantically, you're performing a KNN operation using a `TreeMap` as your datastructure of choice. While this makes sense in that it internally stores keys in comparative order, it doesn't make sense to use a `Map` for an operation that will almost undoubtedly be required to break ties. Here's why:

```
int k = 2;
TreeMap<Double, Text> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(1.0, new Text("close"));
map.put(1.0, new Text("equally close"));
map.put(1500.0, new Text("super far"));
// ... your popping logic...
```

Which are the two closest points you've retained? `"equally close"` and `"super far"`. This is due to the fact that you can't have two instance of the same key. Thus, your algorithm is incapable of breaking ties. There are a few things you could do to fix that:

**First**, if you're set on performing this operation in the `Reducer` and you *know* your incoming data will not cause an `OutOfMemoryError`, consider using a different sorted structure, like a `TreeSet` and build a custom `Comparable` object that it will sort:

```
static class KNNEntry implements Comparable<KNNEntry> {
    final Text text;
    final Double dist;

    KNNEntry(Text text, Double dist) {
        this.text = text;
        this.dist = dist;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(KNNEntry other) {
        int comp = this.dist.compareTo(other.dist);
        if(0 == comp)
            return this.text.compareTo(other.text);
        return comp;
    }
}
```

And then instead of your `TreeMap`, use a `TreeSet<KNNEntry>`, which will internally sort itself based on the `Comparator` logic we just built above. Then after you've gone through all the keys, just iterate through the first `k`, retaining them in order. This has a drawback, though: if your data is truly big, you can overflow the heapspace by loading all of the values from the reducer into memory.

**Second option**: make the `KNNEntry` we built above implement `WritableComparable`, and emit that from your `Mapper`, then use [secondary sorting](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/data-algorithms/9781491906170/ch01.html) to handle the sorting of your entries. This gets a bit more hairy, as you'd have to use lots of mappers and then only one reducer to capture the first `k`. If your data is small enough, try the first option to allow for tie breaking.

But, back to your original question, you're getting an `OutOfBoundsException` because the index you're trying to access does not exist, i.e., there is no "@" in the input `String`.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your suggestions. I'll try to implement the first approach that you offered. But the value emitted from the map contains @ sign in it. Because the output of the first version is exactly what I expect (class@distance). After adding new lines to find the most common key, it starts complaining about this index bounds.

Comment: Check my edit. I rewrote your reducer. I think it may have been an issue with `tmp`. Try that and see if it works...